# What is the difference between SqlCommand.CommandTimeout and SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout?

Tags: .net, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Is there any difference between `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` and `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout` in .NET?

Comment: is this specific to MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Yes. [`CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) is how long a single command can take to complete. [`ConnectionTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) is how long it can take to establish a connection to the server to start with.

For instance, you may be executing relatively long-running queries - it's perfectly okay for them to take 10 minutes to complete, but if it took 10 minutes to make the connection to start with, you'd know that something was badly wrong.

Comment: Out of curiosity:
Since the default timeout is 30 seconds, what happens if I set CommandTimeout to 60 seconds but do not change ConnectionTimeout from the default?

Comment: For the sake of argument, let's say I have a !**&#Q@? query that takes 32 seconds to run. If I set SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 40 but leave SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout at its default (presumably 30), will the connection timeout? In other words, do I have to set both properties? It sounds like you are saying "no," but I must have forgotten about the SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout property and started questioning whether setting CommandTimeout does everything I need it to.

Comment: flipdoubt - the CommandTimeout will affect the query, the ConnectionTimout won't. 

The ConnectionTimout isn't a timeout for the connection to peform queries - it's just the timeout for the connection to connect to the database in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet do CommandTimeout and ConnectionTimeout, both generate the same common exception ? Or different
 exceptions ?

Comment: @Yasser: I don't know, i'm afraid.

Comment: Keep in mind that CommandTimeout appears to apply to only up until the point where the first row is returned from SQL Server to the client code.  Eg, if you have a query that returns the first row within 30 seconds, but the complete rowset takes hours to return, setting the timeout to 30 seconds will not timeout the query and the query will run for hours.  This is mainly the case if you don't have blocking operators (such as an Order by) on the LHS of your execution plan.  (Posting because I spent 2 days debugging this and no other reference on the subject)

Comment: @Yasser I'd a problem with this these days and I can say: both ConnectionTimeout and CommandTimeout generate the same exception (with the -2 code on SqlException.Number)

Answer (score 33):

**`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`** = timeout limit for your SQL query. Means,  how much time a (eg: `SELECT`, `UPDATE`) query can take for its execution. If it exceeds `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`, then it stops execution. A command timeout error will occur.

**`SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout`** = timeout limit for your connection. Means, how much time your connection object can try to connect. If it exceeds the specified time, it stops connecting. A connection timeout error will occur.

Answer (score 11):

`ConnectionTimeout` specifies the duration to wait before timing out when attempting to **open** an `SqlConnection`. It is relevant to the `Connection.Open()` command.

while

`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` specified the duration for an SqlCommand to wait before timing out. This happens after a connection has been opened and one of the `ExecuteXXX` methods have been called on the Command object.

Answer (score 8):

Additional Info

Default value of `CommandTimeout` is 30 seconds. Zero(0) indicates no limit. You can set `CommandTimeout` value in Coding only.

Default value of `ConnectiontTimeout` is 15 seconds. Zero(0) indicates no limit as well. Less than zero value (minus value) will get `ArgumentException`. You can set `ConnectionTimeout` value in both Coding and Config file.

Answer (score 0):

```
select @@LOCK_TIMEOUT //get the TIMEOUT,default is -1
set LOCK_TIMEOUT = 600//set TIMEOUT with ms
```

Comment: This is a 3rd type of timeout. Not one of the two the topic owner asks about. And doesn't answer the question. I won't -1 it, because I don't know what was the question before edits.

Answer (score 0):

Quick note regarding CommandTimeout, since it is a property of both Connection and Command objects...

The CommandTimeout setting on a Connection object has no effect on the CommandTimeout setting on a Command object on the same Connection; that is, the Command object's CommandTimeout property does not inherit the value of the Connection object's CommandTimeout value.

So the CommandTimeout setting on a Connection object only affects commands executed under the Connection object only (without using a Command object).

e.g. When you're connecting to a Stored Proc and adding parameters to the command object, and executing the Command object using a Connection Object's connection, then you would need to set CommandTimeout on the Command object and the ConnectionTimeout on the Connection object to override both defaults.  Setting the CommandTimeout on the Connection Object will not override the default timeout for the Command Object commands.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtimeout-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/connectiontimeout-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15