# Difference between command timeout and connection time out

Tags: asp.net, sql

What is the difference between connection timeout and command timeout?

In our application sometimes it is showing a timeout error. When we increased the command timeout value to 100(from default 30), its working. Is there any issue in increasing the command timeout value.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between SqlCommand.CommandTimeout and SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847264/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlcommand-commandtimeout-and-sqlconnection-conne)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned connection timeout is timeout for establishing connection with DB server. Command timeout is timeout for command execution.

Extending command timeout is possible but when doing this in ASP.NET you should be also aware of request execution timeout. You can set it in code via `Server.ScriptTimeout` or globally in `httpRuntime/@executionTimeout`. Default value for .NET 2.0+ is 110s.

But generally this is most probably wrong way to architect application. Unless you are doing some heavy online reporting wich will be rarely executed no one will want to use it.

Answer (score 7):

ConnectionTimeout is the time your code should wait when trying to open the connection to the DB

CommandTimeout is the time your code should wait for your SQL code to execute.

If you're hitting command timeout your SQL is taking a long time to execute, so you may want to [check your query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177500.aspx). If your query is optimized, then raising the command timeout may be the only thing to make your client work.