# EF 6 - Error taking too long

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

When using the following connection string
`Server=DoesNotExists; Database=DoesNotExistsEither; User ID=bla; Password=bla; Connection Timeout=5;`
shouldn't any command against this connection string fail in 5 seconds?!? in my local machine it's taking about 30sec

**Edit1**
If i change the timeout to 20, it takes 1 min to fail...

Answer (score 1):

Command timeout and connection timeout are not the same thing.

- Connection timeout: maximum time to (try to) establish connection to database
- Command timeout: maximum time a command is allowed to run

So in short: no, a command against that connectionstring should not fail after 5 seconds, if a connection is established.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219534/difference-between-command-timeout-and-connection-time-out) post.

Comment: if you take a look at the connection string you will see that the connection will never be established because neither the server nor the database exists...

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that :-)

Comment: @Leonardo, did you take a look at what your `Context.Connection.ConnectionTimeout` or `Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionTimeout` says?