# SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout Property

Tags: c#

I tried to set ConnectionTimeout of SqlConnection object (C#). But it is read-only property. Default timeout to establish connection is specified as 15 seconds. I want to increase the timeout to 60 seconds.

> Is there any other way to set ConnectionTimeout property?

Comment: The timeout is specified by the connection string used to initialize the `SqlConnection` object.  See the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx

Comment: Change Timeout Setting in Web Config

Comment: In web.config replace Connect Timeout=15 with   Timeout=60

Comment: @Namfuak Actually I referred the link before ask question... I didn't see the example as it was collapsed.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the connection timeout in the connection string your pass to the SqlConnection instance.

```
"Connection Timeout=60"
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's for one or two query probs then you can set the CommandTimeout property.

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommandTimeout"].ToString());
```

Comment: CommandTimeout and ConnectionTimeout are not identical. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847264/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlcommand-commandtimeout-and-sqlconnection-conne) for an explanation of it.

Comment: yes that's y I have writen in my answer if one or two query exceution take more time then set the CommandTimeout