# Why does NHibernate session.Query<T>().Delete() timeout?

Tags: sql, .net, nhibernate

I discovered that since NHibernate 5.0 I can call the following code to delete all records of a table:

```
session.Query<T>().Delete();
```

It executes the code on the database without copying it across the network, which should improve performance a lot.
But this query times out.

I get the following error:

```
Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I've tried setting the Connection Timeout setting in my connectionstring to 0 and to 3600, but it makes no difference.

My table only has about 200 records. But one column is a base64 encoded pdf, so it is quite big and the query would take a few seconds.

What else can I try?

Comment: I've managed to get past this error for now using session.Query<T>().Timeout(600).Delete();.
But i feel like this is a temporary work-around. I would appreciate a better explanation/understanding of why this is needed.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your database (SQL Server?) activity in isolation? For example, if you run the query `DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 1;` (or whatever the correct query is) what's the performance like? Is there any contention on that table that's causing the `DELETE` to be blocked?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to increase the command timeout.

Note that there is a difference between [connection timeout and command timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847264/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlcommand-commandtimeout-and-sqlconnection-conne).

You can set the default command timeout (in seconds) for ADO.NET commands created by NHibernate using the command_timeout NHibernate session configuration property. There are multiple ways to do that depending on what method you use to configure NHibernate. Here are the basics: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/session-configuration.html