# ASP.NET SQL Server Command Timeout Not Working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

We're using ASP.NET 4.5 with SQL Server 2016. We have some queries that are running for longer than the default SqlCommand.CommandTimeout value. I want these queries to fail with an error. They should not be taking as long as they are, and while they continue running, they are impacting performance. We haven't changed the default command timeout value, so it should still be 30 seconds. I have queries running as long as 600 seconds. This is in our development environment, so I have debug=true on, but I thought that was just for page timeout. We are not using a context connection. There are some queries that DO seem to respect CommandTimeout, but many do not -- they run too long regardless of the 30-second default value.

Comment: The first rule when asking questions - ask the question...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847264/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlcommand-commandtimeout-and-sqlconnection-conne