# Connection Timeout SQL c#

Tags: c#, sql, connection-timeout

I have a project and when I try to run it and the data test is big I have always a connection timeout.
I added "***sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;***" but still not working. 
What could am I doing wrong?

*This is my code*:

```
public void createCode(String ce, int ord, String beh, int wkd)
{
        String strSql = "";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(getConexion());

        try
        {
            if (conexion.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conexion.Open();

            //The insert works fine in sql server
            strSql = "Insert into x with values"; 

            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, conexion);
            sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            throw new Exception("Error creating Code. " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                conexion.Close();
        }

}
```

Comment: Please, provide an error message and connection string (obfuscating its secret parts). It is important to distinct two different timeout types: [ConnectionTimeout and CommandTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847264/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlcommand-commandtimeout-and-sqlconnection-conne). Which timeout does cause error in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to set transaction timeout in your config file, like so;

```
<system.transactions>
   <defaultSettings timeout="01:00:00" />
</system.transactions>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was the problem! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar() is not correct for your script, try using sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() instead and remove timeout.

```
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strSql, conexion);
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Check each function, ExecuteScalar tries to return first value from a select, while ExecuteNonQuery does not retrieve any value, just gets num of rows affected.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is not the problem because I have been using this from years. But thank you David.

Comment: So if you are sure your script and sql is ok, you may use sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0 and it won't fail due to sql timeout.